# Steam repeatedly pauses downloads

Tags: steam

**The problem:** when I am downloading anything with Steam, no matter where I am or what I am connected to, it pauses the download after a few seconds.

**Behavior:**

- Select item to download
- Navigate to library -> downloads
- [probz] Game is displayed "downloading", network speed listed, etc (normal behavior)
- [see **Picture 1** below]
- After a few seconds, game stops downloading
- Game is now listed as "update required (not queued)"
- [see **Picture 2** below]
- Click "move to top of queue"
- goto [probz]

**Picture 1**

[image]

**Picture 2**

[image]

I can workaround this by babysitting the "move to top of queue" button but for large games this isn't practical.

**Things I have tried:**

- Wired connection
- Using a different network (many, many different networks)
- Changing Steam download server/location
- Reinstalling Steam
- Deleting tons of Steam files and redownloading them
- Freeing up disk space
- Changing download speed/limit on Steam
- Stopping background programs/other internet accessors
- Adding "-tcp" flag to Steam launch options
- Running as administrator
- Crying

This is a problem I've been having for some time and have tried many solutions (see above). I'd love to see a definitive solution to it, especially since I pretty much can't play any game > 1 gb.

**OS:** Windows 7 Professional, 64-bit

**System:** Lenovo T420 (laptop), Intel i7-2620M, 8gb ram, NVIDIA NVS 4200M

**Connection:** Up to 45 mpbs AT&T UVerse (usually clocks in at around 30-something)

**EDIT:** I would like to note that I used to work in CS (see my Stack Overflow profile), so I do know how to do things like "make sure your internet connection works", "don't let other programs hog bandwidth", and "disable background processes". Because my internet connection works perfectly for everything else I do, including high-bandwith activities (gaming, netflix, other downloading) I would guess that it is not the problem. Especially since I can workaround through queue babysitting (see above). The ONLY problem I have is with Steam, and ONLY when downloading new games.

Thanks for the suggestions so far.

Comment: Probably lack of disk space. Happens to me every now and then.

Comment: I have 38 gigabytes free, just cleaned out all the games I don't play anymore.

Comment: System specs? OS?

Comment: Edited to add, although I am hoping it's a generalize-able problem.

Comment: dumb question, but do you have multiple drives?  maybe your steam download drive is on a hard drive that's full?  Also do you have something like netlimiter installed that's automatically throttling steam?

Comment: I only have one drive, and nothing like a netlimiter. I didn't always have this problem, it started about six months ago.

Comment: Additionally, I CAN still download games - it's just very, very slow.

Comment: hmm, have you tried downloading via something else and not steam?  is this a steam only issue?

Comment: I have no problems with downloads via any other system. Sometimes I torrent the game files and copy them into the Steam folder or download the DRM-free version from Humble Bundle. Not always a viable solution, unfortunately.

Comment: Do you have multiple hard drives? Can you verify which hard drive your steam library is on?

Comment: Have you checked: [**troubleshooting steam connection**](https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=1456-EUDN-2493) or [**programs that may interfere with steam**](https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=9828-SFLZ-9289) or [**disabling background applications**](https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=8043-EUJN-5239) ? Bonus track: [**VPN software**](http://www.reddit.com/r/Steam/comments/1lwxqo/)

Comment: have you tried a different NIC?  like using a usb wireless dongle instead of the built in one for your laptop.  Also tried running steam as an administrator?

Comment: How fast is your internet connection ?

Comment: You could also try opening Steam in TCP (-tcp as launch option). Also be sure to check your router (if any) [port forwarding](https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=8571-GLVN-8711) settings.

Comment: That is a very interesting suggestion. I just tried it (-tcp) and it seemed to make the download go a little longer between pauses (although it's difficult to quantify) but does not appear to solve the problem.

Comment: See if your steam console logs anything (open steam in -dev mode).

Comment: 2019, and still facing the same problems.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try disabling ANY processes that might interfere with your downloading (I fixed mine by disabling Skype). You can find the processes here: https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=9828-SFLZ-9289 Let me know if this helped!

Comment: Honestly, I'm just gonna mark this as the correct answer. I did a fresh install of Windows on my computer and that fixed it. Very helpful information though.

Comment: This didn't work for me... the only program I had on that list was AnyDVD, I quit that, restarted Steam, still no joy. Changed my region to the nearest "(Comcast)" labeled region (since Comcrap is the only real broadband provider in my area) for best peering, restarted Steam again, and now it seems happy. Changing to another nearby (but not Comcast-labeled) region did not help me either.

Comment: Worked for me on Windows 10

Answer (score 7):

Have you tried changing the download restrictions Steam asks you for when changing the download region?

[image]

You can get there by clicking Steam --> Settings --> Downloads

When you change your region, you should be prompted to change your download speed (Modem towards faster speed, Dial-Up towards slower.

Could be the issue you're having. I have had this issue previously, but by changing my download speed to No limit (despite having an average 2mb/s), it helped fix it.

I would daresay this though; it seems [plenty of others are having the same issues as you have as well](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&es_th=1&ie=UTF-8#q=steam%20pausing%20downloads%20for%20no%20reason), albeit for different reasons.

Comment: Yes that's the other thing that can affect it.  Try switching your preferred region to somewhere else and see if it improves the situation

Comment: I just checked the download restrictions - it is set to "No limit". I have tried many different regions as well. :/

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, I've been looking for a solution for quite some time. The problem is that most other problems have to do with internet connection, which isn't the problem (since I can workaround through babysitting the download).

Comment: @Dustin I'll also wager a guess, but I've been having this problem on and off, and I believe it may be tied to having a "no Download Limit". I've checked here: https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=9498-WPDF-3220, and Steam recommends setting the download speed to the one CLOSEST to your actually connection.  At this point though, it's just a guess, so naturally, what is your internet/ISP connection speed?

Comment: It's 45 mbps ("up to", usually checks in at around 34). ATT Uverse. Had this problem with my last provider as well. Also anywhere else I use my laptop. I'll try setting the speed.
EDIT: does not appear to help

Comment: @Dustin I'll still keep hunting for solutions, don't count me out yet, but sorry I haven't been really able to help for now

Comment: Don't worry, glad for any help. Especially since it's a common problem, always nice to have something on stack exchange people will use and can find.